# Configure microsoft teams incoming webhook json payload

Tags: json, https, postman, office365, microsoft-teams

I am trying to set up an incoming webhook to a Microsoft teams channel using the `incoming webhook` connector.
The payload that I am trying to send from my platform looks like this and is form CleverTap (which is failing so I'm trying to debug it using postman). but I am getting the error `Summary or Text is required.`

```
{
  "profiles": [
    {
      "email": "jack@gmail.com",
      "identity": "foo",
      "objectId": "-g55b74fb1030740e4a4931910a8abb862",
      "profileData": {
        "Last Score": 308,
        "High Score": 308,
        "Replayed": true
      },
      "name": "Jack"
    }
  ]
}
```

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. will I need to change the JSON payload according to the adaptive card syntax for teams to accept the incoming webhook? If so, where can I add my custom payload in the adaptive card JSON body?
3. are there other authentication factors at the webhook endpoint (do I have to whitelist the ip address from where the POST message is being sent from)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To send a message using incoming webhook, you must post a JSON payload to the webhook URL. This payload should be in the form of [O365 Connector card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#office-365-connector-card). Payload of any other format is not acceptable in Teams. Here is an [Example Connector card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using#example-connector-message) that you can post. You can now also send an Adaptive card using incoming webhook. Please check the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using#the-flow-for-sending-adaptive-cards-via-an-incoming-webhook-is-as-follows).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it, by just adding the summary key that they asked for. I think this should do the trick:

```
{   "summary": "summary",
    "profiles": [
    {
      "email": "jack@gmail.com",
      "identity": "foo",
      "objectId": "-g55b74fb1030740e4a4931910a8abb862",
      "profileData": {
        "Last Score": 308,
        "High Score": 308,
        "Replayed": true
      },
      "name": "Jack"
    }   ] }
```